# How to show loading while moving between pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I would like to have in my jsp when the user clicks on the submit button, a loading message or an image is shown while moving between the pages. So, how can I do that?

I tried to use some javascripts, but I did not success.
Thanx

Answer (score 3):

If it is a complete page change, **the loading indicator is already here in every browser**.

If you update only a part of a page through AJAX, you may use **AJAX progress indicator**. According to the JavaScript framework you use, **implementations may be different**, so see the documentation or complete your question by specifying the framework you use.